# VB.NET Programmatically login as Administrator

Tags: vb.net, admin, uac, rights

I'm facing a problem kinda hard to solve, I already read a lot of questions about the Administrators Rights .NET app but is almost all about the UAC popup message to login as Admin.
What I want is: When I start my application, the fisrt thing to do before run all the code is login as Admin to grant the application Administrator Rights without ask anything to the User.

Any ideas?

Comment: All the Malware writers would love this ability as well.  Maybe that's why it's not possible?  The UAC prompt isn't there just to annoy the user...

Comment: How can a login as admin be a Malware? I have the user and password and all I have to know is how to login programmatically. I need it for run my company project in their client PC's to sucessfull process the application updates with admin rights

Comment: It looks like there may be some app-specific workarounds like ElevatedShortcut: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/38411-ElevatedShortcut-bypass-the-UAC-prompt!.  Seems interesting, though personally in an enterprise environment, it would make me nervous.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is why does your app need to run with elevated privileges? If you need that, you can use an application manifest to request elevation and then educate your users that they must confirm elevation. But you cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design.

[FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510)

Excerpt:

> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.

Bill

Comment: You have an enterprise with 100 normal users and only 1 admin, right? So the point of use silently-elevated privileges is for that normal users be able to execute the app processes that require admin rights. So all the enterprises now are going to give their admin credentials to the normal users execute their app's?

Comment: Must be a solution out there... I tried one piece of code to let me silently-elevated privileges but I think is not working so I came here asking for your help. [link]http://nujakcities.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/use-vb-net-to-impersonate-a-domain-user/

Comment: As already stated: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. To install application updates that require admin rights, you must use a different approach, such as a service.

Comment: @B1GB0Y: No, the flaw in your logic is that your user application should not under any circumstances require admin privileges to run normally if you really want the security benefits of low-privilege user accounts.  Either give the users the exact needed privileges to run the app, or design it so admin privileges are required very rarely, such as for first-time setup or routine updates.  We went through this exact same thing with some of our own applications.  I refactored the logic that requires admin access to first-time install only, which is an exceptional case.